# Next.JS deprecation message with custom server

Tags: next.js

I'm using a custom server.js for routing which uses something like this:

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer((req, res) => {
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
        const rootStaticFiles = ['/robots.txt', '/sitemap.xml', '/favicon.ico'];

        if (rootStaticFiles.indexOf(parsedUrl.pathname) > -1) {
          const path = join(__dirname, 'static', parsedUrl.pathname);
          app.serveStatic(req, res, path);
        } else {
          handler(req, res);
        }
    }).listen(3000);
});
```

And when I run it, there's this warning about the 'url' property, but I don't know ho to resolve it. It seems to me that withRouter doesn't apply here. Could someone help please?

Comment: add the warning to your question

Comment: oh, I just checked the logs and it's gone. Probably after one of the updates of Next.js

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it looks like they solved it with one of the updates. It does not appear anymore.